# Greater than threshold non-overlapping times in cell array MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, vectorization

I have a `nx3` cell array with `start time`, `end time` of an event and a `place` column that is not relevant for this case but must be kept for later purposes. Each row has one event. Times are in seconds. I want to create a function to filter the times so that:

`end_time(i) + threshold < start_time(i+1) for any given i within the array`

if such condition is not met, events should be 'merged' from `start_time(i) to end_time(i+n)` given that `end_time(i+n) + threshold < start_time(i + n + 1)`. That is, the new start time should be `start_time(i)` and the new end time should be `end_time(i +n)` that meets condition. All other rows should be dropped.

I have been thinking an efficient way to do this but I find myself lost

The example cell is below

```
A = 

[17.9174]    [17.9386]    'NYC'
[20.3504]    [20.3628]    'NYC'
[26.7564]    [26.7804]    'NYC'
[26.7956]    [26.8016]    'NYC'
[26.8017]    [26.9000]    'NYC'
[27.7117]    [27.8000]    'NYC'
```

The desired output for threshold 0.2 should be

A =

```
[17.9174]    [17.9386]    'NYC'
[20.3504]    [20.3628]    'NYC'
[26.7564]    [26.9000]    'NYC'
[27.7117]    [27.8000]    'NYC'
```

Comment: I guess you meant for threshold 0.02 in your example?

Comment: I've not seen your solution and where you got lost. But I will try to provide my hint to your question.

Answer (score 0):

`for` loop with `break` will definitely solve your problem. I suggest you start from there. This is usually the fastest means and also helps validate your approach.

Matlab does provide some convenient functions for this type of question and utilizes their famous vectorization efficiency to elegantly code it. In case you're not familiar with them, I would say read the document for the following functions

`diff`, `cell2mat`,`>`

The proposed approach is then

1. Take the first 2 columns in your cell array and convert it to the numeric array form. Hint:`cell2mat`
2. Calculate difference between two columns. Hint: `diff` (with additional arguments).
3. Find the index that satisfies your criteria in the resulting vector in 2. Hint: `>` or any logical comparison operator you like to use here.
4. Create a new cell array based on the logical index resulting in 3. Hint: [Logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)

Sure the answer can be one liner but that's not what we should concern. Happy solving problem and coding in Matlab.

Comment: The question is how to make diff use data from 2 different columns and rows. I don't want this `diff(cell2mat(A(:,1:2)),1,2)`, that's the duration of each event. I want to see if from the end of one event to the beginning of another there's less time than a 0.2 threshold. I'm lost in the sense that writing a for loop to deal with subseting the (i,2) and (ith+1,1) element, making the comparison, if the comparison meets good, otherwise throws away it's kind of cumbersome. I thought there would be another more efficient way